# Console Program Just Closes Without Any Errors

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am new to C#. I made a console application. The compiler isn't saying there is an error. However when I run it, it closes when I get to this part. In fact, the debugging output doesn't even show any errors! I am using **visual studio express 2012 for windows desktop** Can someone help me?

```
        double vari1, vari2;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value");
        vari1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (vari1 < 10000)
        {
            vari2 = (vari1 * .15);
        }
        else if (vari1 < 150000)
        {
            vari2 = (vari1 * .20);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nope");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps show the error message?  We need some more information, along with what you have tried and/or why you think it is failing.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the debugger and stepping through this section to see where the problem lies? (FWIW the only call here that would be likely to throw is `double.Parse()`, if you enter something that can't be parsed.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to be more specific. The tags indicate that it's related to C#, and "programming error" explains nothing about the problem you're having (what would "programming error" mean if you searched this site for C# problems? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and using the debugger to determine where the problem is occurring?

Comment: `double.Parse` will throw an exception if you give it a bad value (i.e. if you enter "foobar", for example). You should use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @cdhowie im thinking maybe the program runs fine, but the console window closes because there is no Console.ReadLine() call after the if-statement?

Comment: What is the problem?  You said there aren't any errors, and that your program is closing.  That seems like correct and expected behavior.  What do you think should be different?

Comment: @MrSykkox That is also possible. It's hard to tell if this is the complete program or not, but if it is then yeah... it doesn't output anything if the input is valid, so it may just be executing as expected.  Either way, using the debugger would verify this and OP could see the flow of the program.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of Console.ReadLine(); :P

Answer (score 3):

Try to add Console.ReadLine() after you If-statement, maybe your program is fine, but just closes because it is finished? Anyway you should also do some error checking on your parsing calls.

```
    double vari1, vari2;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter value");
    vari1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (vari1 < 10000)
    {
        vari2 = (vari1 * .15);
    }
    else if (vari1 < 150000)
    {
        vari2 = (vari1 * .20);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nope");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```